# My @Cacheable seems to be ignored (Spring)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, caching

I have to cache the result of the following `public` method :

```
    @Cacheable(value = "tasks", key = "#user.username")
    public Set<MyPojo> retrieveCurrentUserTailingTasks(UserInformation user) {
        Set<MyPojo> resultSet;
        try {
            nodeInformationList = taskService.getTaskList(user);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new ApiException("Error while retrieving tailing tasks", e);
        }
        return resultSet;
    }
```

I also configured Caching here :

```
@Configuration
@EnableCaching(mode = AdviceMode.PROXY)
public class CacheConfig  {

@Bean
public CacheManager cacheManager() {
    final SimpleCacheManager cacheManager = new SimpleCacheManager();
    cacheManager.setCaches(Arrays.asList(new ConcurrentMapCache("tasks"),new ConcurrentMapCache("templates")));
    return cacheManager;
}

@Bean
public CacheResolver cacheResolver() {
    final SimpleCacheResolver cacheResolver = new SimpleCacheResolver(cacheManager());
    return cacheResolver;
}

}
```

I assert the following :

1. Cache is initialized and does exist within Spring Context
2. I used jvisualvm to track `ConcurrentMapCache` (2 instances), they are
   there in the heap but empty
3. Method returns same values per user.username
4. I tried the same configuration using spring-boot based project and
   it worked
5. The method is public and is inside a Spring Controller
6. The annotation `@CacheConfig(cacheNames = "tasks")` added on top of my
   controller

**Spring version 4.1.3.RELEASE**
**Jdk 1.6**

Update 001 :

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/{kinematicId}/status/{status}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public DocumentNodeWrapper getDocumentsByKinematicByStatus(@PathVariable String kinematicId, @PathVariable String status, HttpServletRequest request) {
    UserInformation user = getUserInformation(request);
    Set<ParapheurNodeInformation> nodeInformationList =  retrieveCurrentUserTailingTasks(user);
    final List<DocumentNodeVO> documentsList = getDocumentsByKinematic(kinematicId, user, nodeInformationList);

    List<DocumentNodeVO> onlyWithGivenStatus = filterByStatus(documentsList);

    return new DocumentNodeWrapper("filesModel", onlyWithGivenStatus, user, currentkinematic);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You have mode `ASPECTJ` which means you are either need to use loadtime weaving or compile time weaving to have aspects applied. If you don't have that (generally most people just use proxies) remove that.

Comment: After analyzing the information given by @M.Deinum, if you still decide to continue with AspectJ, you need to add `@EnableLoadTimeWeaving` annotation.

Comment: @M.Deinum I just removed ASPECTJ and used PROXY (question updated) it still skipping the Cacheable annotation and the method is called all the time. mithun use I added the annotation and the javaagent and it didn't worked also. Thanks

Comment: How/where are you calling `retrieveCurrentUserTailingTasks`? Is the caching configuration in the same context as your bean with the `@Cacheable` annotation? If not it will not work.

Comment: @M.Deinum ``retrieveCurrentUserTailingTasks`` is a public method inside a controller. Cache is configured into same `MvcConfig` bean

Comment: That isn't answering my question, how is this method called.

Comment: The method is called inside the controller method. Please refer to the update in the question. Thanks

Comment: Internal method calls don't have AOP applied (they don't pass through the proxy) on them and hence it isn't working. Instead you probably want to put it in the `TaskService` instead.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Is the calling method `getDocumentsByKinematicByStatus()` in the same bean as the cacheable method ? If true, then this is a normal behavior because you're not calling the cacheable method via proxy but directly.